# How to add value to existing value using PyMongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I am trying to update/create a new dataset and combine the previous value with the new one.

This is how it looks like in my Python script right now.

```
dailyDataset = {
    "pId" : pub,
    "oId" : off,
    "payout" : +addPayout,
}
db[dbName].update( { 'pId' : publisher, 'oId' : offer.id },  {"$set" : dailyDataset }, True)
```

What I try to achieve is, if the dataset pId and oId exists use the current value from "payout" and add the value from addPayout.

E.g. payout = 1.22 and addPayout = 1.22 result should be 2.44.

Any tip is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc) operator:

```
db[dbName].update( { 'pId' : publisher, 'oId' : offer.id },  {"$inc" : {'payout':1.22}}, True)
```