# PyMonogo - from a list, setting new field or adding to field if it exists

Tags: python, pymongo

```
adjustments = [
   ['Capital','','100'],
   ['Training','100',''],
   ['Training','200',''],
   ]
   
  for a in adjustments:
      query = { "Account": a[0] }
      newvalues = { "$set": { "Adj_DR": a[1], "Adj_CR": a[2] } }
      col.update_one(query, newvalues)
```

Setting `Adj_DR` and `Adj_CR` to `a[1]` and `a[2]` respectively works. However when an account already exists, I would like the value to be added. i.e. `Adj_DR` for `Training` should equal 300. Currently, the code only sets `Adj_DR` to 200, as it is the last value in the list (and simply overwrites the 100). I have tried using `$inc`, but struggling understand how I could make it work here.

I have attempted to use the answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725602/how-to-add-value-to-existing-value-using-pymongo) - however, no success.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's what `$inc` is for. But it works probably only with numbers.

This should work:

```
for a in adjustments:
    query = { "Account": a[0] }
    newvalues = { "$inc": { "Adj_DR": int(a[1]), "Adj_CR": int(a[2]) } }
    col.update_one(query, newvalues)
```